# Can anybody provide the classification of unsupervised learning algorithm?

Tags: machine-learning, unsupervised-learning

***Please, provide the detailed classification of unsupervised machine learning algorithm.***

Comment: Sobhan. Cross Validated (http://stats.stackexchange.com/) is probably better suited to your question. And have a look at their meta section (http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/ so that you better formulate your question. That will insure you more and better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Unsupervised models can be of several types: Clustering, Representation Learning, Dimensionality Reduction, Anomaly Detection and Search (as in nearest neighbours or Information Retrieval) among many others.